# Imagick resize image with padding

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I have wrote function which should resize given image into box and add white padding around the image from top and bottom

```
 public function resizeToBox($MAX_SIZE, $path) {


      $im = new \Imagick($this->fullPath);

      $width=$this->width;
      $height=$this->height;
      if($width > $MAX_SIZE || $height > $MAX_SIZE) {
       $aspect = $width / $height;
       if($width > $height) {
        $width = $MAX_SIZE;
        $height = intval($MAX_SIZE / $aspect);
       } else {
        $height = $MAX_SIZE;
        $width = intval($MAX_SIZE * $aspect);
       }
      }
      $offsetX =  intval(($MAX_SIZE - $width)/2);
      $offsetY =  intval(($MAX_SIZE - $height)/2);


      $im->resizeImage($width, $height, \imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
      $im->cropImage ($MAX_SIZE, $MAX_SIZE, 0,0);
      $im->setGravity(\imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
      $im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
      $im->extentImage($MAX_SIZE,$MAX_SIZE,$offsetX ,$offsetY);

      $resizePath =  $path. "/" . $this->name . "." . $this->imageMime;
      $im->writeImage( $resizePath);


   }
```

when I do

```
$im->extentImage($MAX_SIZE,$MAX_SIZE,0 , 0);
```

my image stays on the top left corner 
and when I do

```
$im->extentImage($MAX_SIZE,$MAX_SIZE,$offsetX ,$offsetY);
```

the top of the images gets cut, not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but if you use `GRAVITY_CENTER` you probably want a zero offset relative to centre.

Comment: I am not sure that the gravity controls work at all. Manually calculating the offset yourself isn't that hard, and would probably work.